# Modules, Signatures, Functors And Making Them Fit Together

Tags: ocaml

I have a simple question about modules and getting them to accommodate signatures and functors. Should we, if we have the opportunity, make the modules fit the functor or should we make the functor fit the modules? I know it depends on what you can modify but what if you are writing the modules, signatures, and functors. I think this will make sense with a small example. Say I have two modules which are/can be 'signature' wise identical except for one function.

```
module One =(*this module has a immutable data container*)
struct
...
(* container->string->container *)
let add_str_container cont str = ...
...
end
```

and

```
module Two =(*this module has a mutable data container*)
struct
...
(* container->string->unit *)
let add_str_container cont str = ...
...
end
```

Now I can fix this dilemma by creating a new function and hiding the fact that one module's add_str_container returns unit and the other returns container.

```
module One =(*this module has a immutable data container*)
struct
...
(* container->string->container *)
let add_str_container cont str = ...(* now this is not exported in the signature *)
(* container->string->container *)
let add_str_aux cont str = add_str_container cont str

...
end
module Two =(*this module has a mutable data container*)
struct
...
(* container->string->unit *)
let add_str_container cont str = ...(* now this is not exported in the signature *)
(* container->string->container *)
let add_str_aux cont str = add_str_container cont str; cont

...
end
```

The addition of add_str_aux and the omission of add_str_container solves the type problem nicely and everything is type correct and simple in the signature and functor. My question is basically - How do you get modules which may contain immutable and mutable containers to a unique signature when mutable containers generally return unit on updates and immutable containers return a new reference to the updated container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is indeed a bad idea, it is still possible to express it, you just need to find an abstraction that will cover both implementations, at least on a syntactic point. For example,

```
module type Container = sig
    type t 
    type elt
    val add : t -> elt -> t
end
```

So, we can provide both imperative and persistent implementation of this interface:

```
 module Persistent : Container = struct
    type t = int list
    type  elt = int
    let add xs x = x :: xs
 end

 module Imperative : Container = struct
    type t = int list ref
    type elt = int
    let add xs x = 
       xs := x :: !xs;
       xs 
 end
```

So we have two implementations that satisfy the same signature, so, it might be tempting to think that they fit into the same abstraction. However, there is a trap here, although they are indeed fit into the same abstraction syntactically, they have different semantics. Let me elaborate on the issue a little bit more. In fact, the type `t -> elt -> t` doesn't require the returned value not to be an alias of the input value, so in a general case, this can happen. However, there is a convention, that if a function takes a value, and returns a value of the same type, then the returned value is not aliased with the input value (at least it is not observable). This makes reasoning about programs much easier. But again, this is only a convention, that is not guaranteed by a type system, or by any other mechanism of the language. That's why we can fit two different implementations into the same signature, and this is because we should be careful when we violate the convention.

There are still cases when such a tick can give a profit. Suppose, you have a generic algorithm, that just needs a container, where it can put data. The algorithm itself, will not rely on a fact, that the values are not aliased. An example of such algorithm can be a graph search, that is parametrized by a container. It will always use the last returned value, and throw away the intermediate containers, so it will work just fine with both persistent and imperative containers. And there is no reason, why such algorithm should be parametrized by the imperative only (or, alternatively, persistent only) containers.

A particular example, of a library, that unifies persistent and imperative data structures would be OCaml Graph library, which provides an interface to which both imperative and persistent graphs fits. So, that an algorithm, can work interchangeably for both cases.

To summarize, it is possible, but it will break a convention, so you should be very careful. You can't catch it with your type system, so, at least, you should consider to choose names carefully, and document your assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer to your question, but the proper reply is: don't do it.

You seem to be assuming that it makes sense to model mutable and immutable data structures with the same interfaces. But I would question that assumption. The differences are much more fundamental than just differences in a few return types. The attempt to shoehorn them into the same signature does more harm than benefit. In fact, I would even recommend using different naming conventions to *emphasise* the difference, not obscure it. It makes programs more readable.

Scala collections tried to unify mutable and immutable interfaces, and I have heard a lot of criticism of that approach. It certainly made them super complicated.

Comment: You provided more of an answer than you think. Basically what you addressed in your reply does give me something to consider when trying to marry functionality together. Thank-you for that bit of knowledge.